# csv rows into separate txt files?

Tags: java, python, csv, text-files

**Task 1:** Read each row from one csv file into one seprate txt file.

**Task 2:** Reverse: in one folder, read text from each txt file and put into a row in a single csv. So, read all txt files into one csv file.

How would you do this? Would Java or Python be good to get this task done in very quickly?

**Update:**
For Java, there are already some quite useful libraries you can use, for example [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or [javacsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/). But better have a look at wikipedia about [csv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) if no knowledge on csv. And this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053761/what-is-a-good-csv-java-utility/2053816#2053816) tells you all the possibilities in Java.

---

**Note**: Due to the simplicity of the question, some one pre-assume this is a homework. I hereby declare it is not.

More background: I am working on my own experiments on machine learning and setting up a large scale test set. I need crawl, scrape and file type transfer as the basic utility for the experiment. Building a lot of things by myself for now, and suddenly want to learn Python due to some recent discoveries and get the feeling Python is more concise than Java for many parsing and file handling situations. Hence got this question.

I just want to save time for both you and me by getting to the gist without stating the not-so-related background. And my questions is more about the second question "Java vs Python". Because I run into few lines of code of Python using some csv library (? not sure, that's why I asked), but just do not know how to use Python. That are all the reasons why I got this question. Thanks.

Comment: How would *you* do this?

Comment: To all who answered, why not just sit next to him in class, answer all the questions the prof asks and take his tests for him?

Comment: @KevinDTimm - Easy to say when the homework tag is added afterwards.

Comment: @BPDeveloper - I added it; you couldn't tell before the tag was in place?

Comment: @KevinDTimm Why do people want to pre-assume guilty??? I am just totally new to Python and try to learn it myself. Sigh~

Comment: In which case, I would assume that you would at least try something yourself.  Asking somebody else to write code for you DOES NOT constitute learning.  (If you are new to python, then why ask about/tag with `java`?) Homework tag removed - but sentiment remains

Comment: @KevinDTimm Sorry for being too concise. Because homework things are way in the history, this did not come up to my mind when I raised the question.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I would probably use http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/ in Java and spent some time wrestling with it. :P

Comment: @StevenRumbalski But I decide to spend more time wrestling with Python by learning it. :P

Comment: @Flake, just because you mentioned machine learning, there are excellent tools for Python doing number crunching and data analysis. Take a look at http://scipy.org it has probably all you need. For machine learning there is http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net which makes use of those libraries you find on scipy.org.

Comment: @Bernhard, thanks a lot for the kind tip. Yes, scikit-learn seems quite promising. ;) One of the reason to pick up Python is that it's really coming up for almost everything I was looking for. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you write there is little need on using something specific for CSV files. In particular for Task 1, this is a pure data I/O operation on text files. In Python for instance:

```
for i,l in enumerate(open(the_file)):
   f = open('new_file_%i.csv' % i, 'w')
   f.write(l)
   f.close()
```

For Task 2, if you can guarantee that each file has the same structure (same number of fields per row) it is again a pure data I/O operation:

```
# glob files
files = glob('file_*.csv')
target = open('combined.csv', 'w')
for f in files:
   target.write(open(f).read())
   target.write(new_line_speparator_for_your_platform)
target.close()
```

Whether you do this in Java or Python depends on the availability on the target system and your personal preference only.

Answer (score 1):

In that case I would use python since it is often more concise than Java.
Plus, the CSV files are really easy to handle with Python without installing something. I don't know for Java.

### Task 1

It would roughly be this based on an example from the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rownumber = 0
    for row in reader:
        g=open("anyfile"+str(rownumber)+".txt","w")
        g.write(row)
        rownumber = rownumber + 1
        g.close()
```

### Task 2

```
f = open("csvfile.csv","w")
dirList=os.listdir(path)
for fname in dirList:
    if fname[-4::] == ".txt":
       g = open("fname")
       for line in g: f.write(line)
       g.close
f.close()
```

Comment: can be improved with `enumerate`.  Consider: `for rownumber, row in enumerate(reader):`.

Answer (score 0):

In python,
Task 1:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as df:
    reader = csv.reader(df)
    for rownumber, row in enumerate(reader):
        with open(''.join(str(rownumber),'.txt') as f:
            f.write(row)
```

Task 2:

```
from glob import glob
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as output:
    for f in glob('*.txt'):
        with open(f) as myFile:
            rows = myFile.readlines()
            output.write(rows)
```

You will need to adjust these for your use cases.